# Card flip animation plugin

Tags: jquery, css

I'm looking for a card flip jquery animation plugin or css3 animation.I've attached the image of it.
So the animation should happen as in like a flip of cards on a deck.
[image]

Any help in finding such a plugin or a css3 effect appriciated.

Comment: see this.. http://www.hscripts.com/scripts/jquery/shuffle-transition.php

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't happy with any of existing shuffle transitions for our flashcard interactive, so I ended up choosing the [Mosaic Jquery Library](http://buildinternet.com/project/mosaic/1.0/). I just used the sliding transitions to mimic the card flip, and then faded divs to bring up the new card.

Here is an example init function:

```
// add our sliding box event
$('.cover').mosaic({
    animation:  'slide', // fade or slide
    speed:       500,
    hover_x:    '900px', // horizontal position of overlay after hover/click 
    hoverdelay: '0',
    mouseevent: 'click'  // click or hover
});
```

My [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/speeves/LcJKX/4/) and a link to [my modified version of the mosaic library](https://github.com/speeves/mosaic/blob/master/js/mosaic.1.0.1.js), which handles click events, in addition to the default hover.